# Do I need to ask before burninating tiny tags?

Tags: discussion, tags, etiquette, burninate-system

There are many pages of tags on SO and many of them are used for only a few questions.

Fortunately, this means that it's super obvious when a tag should go (namely when there's no wiki and existing popular tags could've been used instead*).

But do I need to ask permission before I burninate these tags? Most are used less than 5 times.

---

Edit: Obviously, having a few questions doesn't automatically mean a tag is bad. It just means that you could read all the questions tagged with it, decide if it's a good tag, and retag everything within a span of 5 minutes.

Also, I'm not talking about "sublanguage" tags as much as `X` and `Y` tags.

For example: [cucumberwithserenity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cucumberwithserenity) = [cucumber](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cucumber) + [serenity-bdd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/serenity-bdd)

(Note that that tag could also be considered a synonym of the slightly more popular [cucumber-serenity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cucumber-serenity), which also lacks a wiki.)

Comment: Yes, you should at least try to verify if your assumption to burninate is correct. That can be done here on meta or informally in a chatroom where you expect subject matter experts to be found. Or head to the [SOCVR](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers)  if no such room exist. The number of questions in a tag, the absence of a tag wiki are not a criteria to start removing a tag.

Comment: Perhaps the tag [tag:relative-time-span] could serve to clarify the criteria for burninate-worthiness? It is so hopelessly specific that probably most of the questions that could be tagged with it have been asked already. All three of them.

Comment: Being exactly 100% certain that "burninate" is not a word in the English Language; I checked [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/burninate-system/info) with no luck, then [google](http://lmgtfy.com/?q=burninate) led me to [this](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Burninate) definition. So the question seems to be about permission requirements for immolating something without just cause - which seems a little paradoxical. I'm just pointing out that meaning isn't always transferred to those of us who are perhaps at least 2 standard deviations older than the mean age here. :p

Comment: @user6170930: Look at the tags, or the related questions, to see what burnination means *on Meta SO*.

Comment: @user6170930 The second hit on google would have let you to http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120640/what-does-it-mean-to-burninate-a-tag

Comment: @Nathan The first link in my comment is the info for the burninate-system tag - so you are asking me to look at the tag I looked at? Which I did - twice. o.O - The tag info is not informative. @ everyone Mostly here I was attempting to gently point out the difficulties involved when communicating in a multi-cultural and multi-generational environment in a mildly humorous way. I can see that I failed. So tough crowd, I'll get my coat ;)

Comment: @user6170930 They're not talking about "burninate system". There's another tag called "burninate request". (I found your comment funny nevertheless.) You would have found more relevant results if you searched using the search bar on Meta (upper right corner, FYI).

Comment: @Laurel Thanks - external validation is always welcome. That's why we are all here chasing virtual reputations I suppose. Anyway it really didn't take me long yesterday to figure out what the question was about and the search bar was a help in that, but I will point out that the question is tagged burninate-system and that's what caused the initial mishap. So now being well informed and having my coat, I'm out the door.

Comment: Well, I didn't actually request that we burninate anything, so that's why I didn't use "burninate request".

Comment: Good point and well made. A subtle distinction that I would not have spotted. I'm a 30 day old noob here, so I suppose it will take a while to properly understand how stuff works. Will do my best not to cause too much trouble in the meantime.

Answer (score 73):

Let's take a counterexample to your approach of "burninate any tags with few tagged questions".

Suppose I were to create a new project called "Unicorny" in JavaScript.

After a few weeks of development, some users of my project decide to ask a question on SO, and create the new tag [unicorny](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unicorny).

Now they've only just started asking about this new up-and-coming project that rivals the biggest buzzwords, so they haven't hardly put any effort into the tag wiki *yet*.

Now imagine some callous user comes along and untags those questions and burninates the tag.

The user defends their actions with "There's no wiki and existing popular tags (such as [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript)) could've been used instead!"

Do you see a problem with this? I do.

Ask before *any* and **all** burninate requests.

Comment: There are some tags that I looked at that seemed bad, yet describe legit things ([like "phonyrails"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/phonyrails)). You can usually tell by looking at the post.

Comment: Honestly... that's kind of a terrible counterexample. A framework tag is a poor candidate for burnination, whether it has 2 questions or 2000. But burninating some trivial one-off like `vowels` or something is not a problem as long as the actual logic is sound.

Comment: @nathan, so how do you know that [tag:vowels] isn't the name of my new framework? You might not have heard of it yet, and there could be some poorly tagged questions lying around as a red herring. My point stands, if you think you found a tag worth burninating, **just ask**.

Comment: @zzzzBov: If a tag *could* hypothetically be used for something valid, but *isn't*, at all, then why is burninating at all inappropriate?

Comment: @NathanTuggy, you're missing my point. If you review a tag and you don't see value in a tag, that doesn't mean that there isn't value in having that tag, it just means that **you've** failed to identify one. Once **the community** determines that a tag has no value (because in all likelihood you're correct) it's **then** ok to burninate. What you seem to be missing is that asking is used as a double-check step to affirm your beliefs. It's not meant to stop burninating from happening, it's just meant to ensure that *when* it happens, it's done correctly. Not everyone is as diligent as you.

Comment: @NathanTuggy I think you misunderstood me. I was saying that we *shouldn't* burninate phonyrails, despite its awkward name.

Comment: @zzzzBov The thing I'd like to point out with smaller tags is you can easily see ALL the questions it has. If it is used for questions about a language/framework, then it should stay. It doesn't matter if a language comes along in the future with the name, because we can just recreate the tag.

Comment: @Laurel, just because you *can* see all the questions doesn't mean you *have* seen all the questions. There is no harm in asking, and it takes very little effort.

Comment: @zzzzBov Are you talking about deleted questions or future questions?

Comment: @Laurel, neither. I'm talking about a pessimistic view that people will be lazy and make mistakes. Better to expect it and provide a simple way to *avoid* mistakes than to give carte blanche and have to deal with cleaning up the mess later.

Comment: @zzzzBov: It would be more accurate to say there's not *much* harm in asking, other than the noise. If you do a quick check in chat I don't care, but I also don't think it's needed if someone is in fact reasonably competent.

Comment: @zzzzBov Do you think that we should be more proactive in preventing these tags from being created in the first place? That should probably be a whole new discussion...

Comment: @Laurel, nah, I'd rather we take more care in destructive processes (closing, deleting, removing) and have more liberty with creative processes (new tags, questions, answers).

Comment: @zzzzBov, while I agree that OP (and everyone else) should **just ask**, I would also say that if you create a new framework and corresponding tag called [tag:vowels], that you would also populate its tag-wiki appropriately, and then it would be obvious to OP and everyone else that the tag refers to a something useful and valid.

Comment: @shoover [... and pray that someones actually read 'em](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/256114/213575)

Answer (score 22):

The specified criteria are bad and wrong. Number of questions in a tag doesn't correlate well to burn-worthiness, and the presence or absence of an excerpt or wiki is not all that relevant either. The fundamental thing is the clarity and usefulness of the concept for tagging, for which there are already criteria to use. [Four, to be precise](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239190/when-to-burninate/239191#239191).

> - Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?
> - Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?
> - Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?
> - Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?

(If a tag is just a combination of two other tags, it's hard to argue that it adds meaningful information, unless it's routinely used to mitigate the five-tag limit.)

There are some auxiliary checks to see how much people care about the tag — questions, wiki, followers, etc — but the first thing is to work out whether the tag should be burninated using the *right* criteria. If you're reasonably sure it should be, **and** it's a trivial tag with just a few questions, then according to Shog9, [it's fine to get going on the process by yourself](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/307124):

> In closing, it's worth noting that none of this particularly matters for tags that only have a tiny handful of questions in them; if one person can knock out a tag in a few minutes, then a huge heavy process surrounding it is completely unnecessary... You don't really even need to bring it up on meta. **But you should still use good judgement, even for small tags**. If the tag isn't actively causing harm, leave it be.

Answer (score -7):

I now have to get 3 people to approve before I may put any rubbish in the bin that I picked up from the road, due to someone in the distance past putting one odd glove in the bin, when the owner may have gone back to find it..   Therefore I now just walk past any rubbish…

I have long ago given up trying to clean up tags with a few questions on them, however useless the tags are……

Comment: This is just a rant, and a nonsensical one at that, with a completely broken analogy. It doesn't address the question whatsoever.

Comment: This answer made me laugh.... +1 even though I disagree. That being said it does look like a rant