# Untrack [reputation-tracker]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request

(Asking permission per [Do I need to ask before burninating tiny tags?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/322335/do-i-need-to-ask-before-burninating-tiny-tags))

[reputation-tracker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reputation-tracker) has 14 questions dating back to mid-2009. The most recent 3 of those should have been asked on Meta SO rather than SO itself. Most of the remaining questions are also tagged Ruby on Rails, which I don't know enough about to evaluate the tag's use here. (I am guessing, since [ruby-on-rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ruby-on-rails), [ruby-on-rails-3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ruby-on-rails-3), and [ruby-on-rails-4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ruby-on-rails-4) have ~250k questions and only 7 of those share [reputation-tracker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reputation-tracker), that the extra tag isn't strictly necessary.)

Kill it with fire?

Comment: Thanks for posting this burnination request and allowing the community to take a close look at it. Please note that burninations are not just tag removals - They are the process of carefully moderating a specific place of Stack Overflow. Avoid only mass-editing the tag out of questions as it is counter-productive. Flag/vote/edit/retag the posts after consensus is reached. For more info, see [Shog9's answer on MSE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/239191/306392) or the [unofficial SOCVR process](https://github.com/SO-Close-Vote-Reviewers/SOCVR-RoomInformation/blob/master/burnination.md#process).

Comment: I wouldn't just go removing the tag. Instead, let's use it as a beacon to guide us to questions that should be closed/migrated/etc.