# Burninate the [sqlcl] tag?

Tags: discussion, status-declined, burninate-request

This is my first considering a burnination. I'm so excited!

... ok, not really.

Anyway: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sqlcl

Only one question on sqlcl, while there are a zillion Oracle questions, so it's not a new tool or anything. Tag wiki does not seem to help anyone any. What do you think?

Comment: Is just **one** question. This is getting ridiculous. BTW, I don't find whatever has the tool to do with programmers. Is mostly a tool used by DB admins.

Comment: You have the edit privlidge.  If you feel that this tag shouldn't exist, just edit it out of the question.  The system will remove it in due time.

Comment: @JAL: This would be my first time doing that and I wasn't sure it was merited.

Comment: The number of questions is really irrelevant.

Answer (score 5):

As the one who originally asked about [burninating tiny tags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/322335), I will tell you that you didn't need to make an entire Meta post about this.

With one question you have several options that you could have done:

- If the question is completely off topic, flag or close vote it.
- Talk to the author of the question
- Remove it yourself and maybe add a more relevant tag. You seem competent enough, use your judgement.
- Found a good pun. It's a *pun*y tag, in any case.

You should read [Shog9's answer here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/307124) for more information about the burnination process.

Comment: The _most_ important of all being finding a good pun of course :D.